# How to ignore 'duplicate entry' exceptions with spring-data/jpa

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

```
@Transactional(noRollbackFor = {SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException.class, ConstraintViolationException.class, DataIntegrityViolationException.class})
public void createLead(List<Info> infos)
{
    for (Info info : infos)
    {
        try
        {
            repo.save(info.toDao());
        }
        // should catch Duplicate entry (SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException, ConstraintViolationException, DataIntegrityViolationException)
        catch (Throwable ignore)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I want to insert all `List<Info>` to the database and rollback if any errors (except for `duplicate entry` occurs), but even with a try/catch and the noRollbackFor configuration, the transaction is being rolledback, why?

Comment: Are you sure those exceptions aren't nested inside a more generic exception which is actually thrown?

Comment: If I understood correctly, `java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException` is wrapped into `org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException`, which is wrapped into `org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException`. I added all of those to `noRollbackFor`.

Comment: Ok. Maybe this method is being called from the context of different transaction and therefore `noRollbackFor` defined on this method is not being respected? It may be the case as you, by default, use `REQUIRED` propagation.

Comment: This method is being called directly from a `@PostMapping` without anything else. Does it create a transaction by default?

Comment: If you call it directly from your controller then yes, this method is being executed inside new transaction unless you have `@PostMapping` method annotated with `@Transactional`.

Comment: What I meant is that you said `Maybe this method is being called from the context of different transaction and therefore`. But I'm calling it from my `@PostMapping` without anything else, so it shouldn't have any other context, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229021/discussion-between-foreign-and-piotr-podraza).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume the exceptions you included in `noRollbackFor` are being thrown at commit time (when the transaction interceptor tries to commit current session) and naturally since the commit is not possible, the transaction is rolled back.

That means Spring respect your request not to rollback on those exceptions but since it's happening in commit phase it simply can do anything else other than rollback transaction and rethrow the exception. There is nothing you can do about it - this is how the mechanism of `@Transactional` work.

Comment: flush should trigger it, no?